# Java button multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm experiencing a following problem. I have designed a GUI in implemented Netbeans GUI builder and I've got several buttons in my program. If I press one of the button it will start running some method that takes about 10 seconds, but there is also a button for cancelling running this method. But while the Button 1 method is running I can not click on any other button in my program, it's like being freezed and I have to wait until the method is done.
I think this has something to do with multithreading, can you guys give me a hint ??

Thanks !

Comment: or maybe your pc can not handle the awesomeness of your code ^^ ?

Comment: See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: You need to use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to run the 10 second method. It will keep your UI responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SwingWorker`.

```
public class MyBackgroundWorker extends SwingWorker<Integer, String> {

  @Override
  protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
    callYourLongTimeTakingMethod();
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Now on your Start button event listener create an object for this `SwingWorker` class and execute it.

```
objMyBGWorker = new MyBackgroundWorker();
objMyBGWorker.execute();
```

And on your cancel button even listener you can call,
`objMyBGWorker.cancel(true);`